# from jquery to angularjs directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm new in creating an angularjs directive. This directive is working. But when i try to use gulp test its saying `$ is not define`

```
.directive('backToTop', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: 'src/client/app/directives/backtop.html',
    link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {

      $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() <= 0) {
          $(element).fadeOut();
        }
        else {
          $(element).fadeIn();
        }

      });

      $(element).on('click', function () {
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'fast');
      });

    }
  };
})
```

Any Suggestions to make it work ? Thanks

Comment: I think there is already a directive for this, check it out [angular-backtop](https://github.com/padsbanger/angular-backtop)

Comment: did you add jquery to your gulp task runner?

Comment: @NarenMurali thanks for sharing this directive i'll try this


MohammadJavadSeyyedi  i just needed it to be converted and im new to gulp to so i don't want to mess with it thanks anyway i'll try to read about it too.

Comment: @Priz You're welcome!